# Como chamar método assíncrono em construtor de classe?

Tags: c#, assincronismo, construtor

Como eu faço para chamar um método marcado como `async` em um construtor de classe?

Comment: Sim, é que é carregado em uma App Android e preciso que seja assíncrono.

Comment: O que esse método faz? Preenche algo da instância?

Comment: @vnbrs, o método me traz as informações que um dado serviço disponibiliza. Usarei eles para preencher um chart

Answer (score 3):

Os construtores não podem ser marcados como `async`. Existe uma [discussão em aberto](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/419) no repositório da linguagem C# no GitHub sobre o assunto.

Dito isso, não existe como chamar um método e esperar por ele com a palavra-chave [`await`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await).

Uma alternativa é criar um método estático que construa o objeto. Veja no exemplo:

```
public static async Task<Foo> Construir() {
    await MetodoAssincrono(); // chamada assíncrona
    return new Foo(); // retorna instância do objeto construído
}
```

Se precisa preencher algo dentro da instância que provém do retorno desse método assíncrono, faça algo assim:

```
public static async Task<Foo> Construir() {
    var instancia = new Foo(); // constrói objeto
    instancia.Dados = await GetDadosAsync(); // preenche o que precisa preencher; chamada assíncrona
    return instancia; // retorna instância do objeto construído
}
```

Ao invés de

```
var obj = new Foo();
```

você teria

```
var obj = await Foo.Construir();
```

Se não quiser um método estático, crie uma função assíncrona de inicialização dentro da sua classe. Após o objeto construído, chame assim:

```
var obj = new Foo();
await obj.Inicializar(); // Inicializar() retorna uma Task que será consumida aqui
```

Comment: Se não era possível eu sabia, pois construtores não podem ser async. Eu vi algo no SOen e estou procurando e não estou encontrando. Um cara fez uma coisa, ele resolveu um problema semelhante ao meu, mas como eu estava, naquele dia procurando outra coisa e vi e agora não sei o endereço daquela solução, mas vou pensar em algo como a sua solução. Verei o que fazer.

Comment: Não lembro exatamente como era, mas pode ser algo parecido com que vc postou